# How to perform joint inference in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I have two or more different Deep Neural Networks (model1, model2,..., modelr) having the same number of layers but different number neurons separately trained with the same datasets, is there a way to perform a joint inference at the test phase, starting from the first network, first and second networks, first, second and third networks, etc? The idea is to investigate the impact of joint inference on the classification accuracy. Thank you.

Comment: So are you trying to load multiple models in tensorflow in the same file?

Comment: Hi Shreyas. What I'm trying to do is to train the first model, and then use its learned weights to initialize and train the second model. However, during training the second model, the first model should be fixed and finally, the third model is also initialized with the second model's learned weights and then train with both first and second models fixed. The idea is to investigate the subset that gives the best dynamic computation range at which learning is easier with minimum complexity as in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.07830.pdf

Comment: You need to read about saving and retrieving checkpoints. See about how to do it in Keras (easier to read code and understand what it means) - about 10 minutes of google search would do. And then do it in TensorFlow - read how to freeze checkpoints - (converting .ckpt files to .pb)